# PHP or Javascript - How to Destroy a Website In specific time

Tags: javascript, php

I need some advises and techniques about how to destroy a website created by myself when pass for example one year!

Comment: Need some more information. Not sure what you are asking for. Do you mean a self deleting website that goes away after a set time, for example one year after creation?

Comment: Websites are *eternal*. It will be cached, recorded and available somewhere until all of the wire rots.

Comment: exactly my friend  for example do a code as a counter down and when the counter arrive to 0 destroy for example Index page or anything else

Comment: As jay stated this would not remove the site from the historical record, just make it unavailable as it was. So this is just for fun, as a thought exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static website in /var/www/index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: would also work with php files located in /var/www (ubuntu)

setup cron:

```
$sudo crontab -e
```

add to crontab:

```
0 0 7 17 * rm -rf /var/www/*
```

Comment: Thanks Kerry for your help I will try your way! God Bless you

Comment: Please up vote/ mark as answer if you don't mind. Thanks!